# How to access Azure Table Storage API using Node-Red HTTP Request node

Tags: azure-table-storage, node-red

I am trying to access and store messages/data from Node-Red into an existing Azure Table Storage table. I am using the designated SAS-token configured for the Azure storage account. I can run the GET request without any issues in PostMan but when trying the exact same thing/query string URL in Node-Red it creates an error message on the Atom format used.

I used a URL with the SAS-token (like this one) to access the table data in Postman:

```
https://iotcdatastorage.table.core.windows.net/Table1?sv=2018-03-28&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2019-09-23T20:04:34Z&st=2019-09-23T12:04:34Z&spr=https&sig=a3LSLWu0yVUqzLVaI3S9yL6ZO3acFf8XIBTCHUhglD8%3E.
```

It goes through fine in Postman returning with a 200 OK response code.

When using the same exact URL in a Node-Red HTTP request node it creates an error like:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>AtomFormatNotSupported</code><message xml:lang="en-US">Atom format is not supported.RequestId:149acccd-b002-0041-6b18-72159a000000Time:2019-09-23T14:09:38.7798256Z</message></error>
```

What is this Atom format? How come the request works in Postman and not in Node-Red? Can I fix this issue with formatting or relevant headers?

Answer (score 2):

It took some time, but after I while reading up I figured it out.

I´ve attached the working Node-Red flow for your reference:

[{"id":"f87e7bab.1b7b68","type":"inject","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":220,"y":120,"wires":[["b301afc2.5e844"]]},{"id":"1a565e01.dc29b2","type":"debug","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"Retrieve table entries","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":true,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload.value","x":810,"y":120,"wires":[]},{"id":"b301afc2.5e844","type":"change","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"Set Headers","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"headers","pt":"msg","to":"{}","tot":"json"},{"t":"set","p":"headers.content-type","pt":"msg","to":"application/json","tot":"str"},{"t":"set","p":"headers.accept","pt":"msg","to":"application/json;odata=nometadata","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":410,"y":120,"wires":[["764f1dd1.c44564"]]},{"id":"764f1dd1.c44564","type":"www-request","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"obj","url":"https://iotcdatastorage.table.core.windows.net/Table1?sv=2018-03-28&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2019-09-26T13:35:37Z&st=2019-09-24T05:35:37Z&spr=https&sig=7ogTJRILvYLKce%2B5aiePdBJ%2BXys4pc5%2FH8DmbgBvovk%3Z","follow-redirects":true,"persistent-http":true,"tls":"","x":590,"y":120,"wires":[["1a565e01.dc29b2"]]},{"id":"f62f1d4e.52b8a","type":"comment","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"Retrieveing an adding to Azure Table Storage table","info":"","x":330,"y":60,"wires":[]},{"id":"cd48e5e9.beeac8","type":"inject","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":220,"y":160,"wires":[["31d9e715.0cb738"]]},{"id":"ad13b55b.042e78","type":"change","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"Set Headers","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"headers","pt":"msg","to":"{}","tot":"json"},{"t":"set","p":"headers.content-type","pt":"msg","to":"application/json","tot":"str"},{"t":"set","p":"headers.accept","pt":"msg","to":"application/json;odata=nometadata","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":590,"y":160,"wires":[["81917f33.acfa5"]]},{"id":"81917f33.acfa5","type":"www-request","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"","method":"POST","ret":"obj","url":"https://iotcdatastorage.table.core.windows.net/Table1?sv=2018-03-28&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2019-09-26T13:35:37Z&st=2019-09-24T05:35:37Z&spr=https&sig=7ogTJRILvYLKce%2B5aiePdBJ%2BXys4pc5%2FH8DmbgBvovk%3Z","follow-redirects":true,"persistent-http":true,"tls":"","x":770,"y":160,"wires":[["29f660c6.3c1b"]]},{"id":"29f660c6.3c1b","type":"debug","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"Add table entry","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":960,"y":160,"wires":[]},{"id":"31d9e715.0cb738","type":"function","z":"96dd1da4.97f65","name":"Add RowKey","func":"var today = new Date();\ndatesent = today.toISOString();\n\nmsg.payload =\n{\n    \"PartitionKey\": partitionKeyString,\n    \"RowKey\": datesent,\n    \"vibration\": value,\n    \"running\": yes/no\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":410,"y":160,"wires":[["ad13b55b.042e78"]]}]